# How to make the drawer go over the action bar?

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview

I added a NavigationView to my DrawerLayout. The problem is that it goes under the action and status bar. I would like it to be above preferably both bars, but I would be happy to get it at least over the action bar.

[image]

Even if the background color of the action bar is transparent it gets darker as the drawer is opened.

[image]

this is how my main activity looks like in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/sideMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_menu_background"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and here is the Kotlin code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var playlistFragment = PlaylistFragment.newInstance()
    private var streamFragment = StreamFragment.newInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
//        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        replaceFragment(playlistFragment)
        sideMenu.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            handleNavigationItemTap(item)
            true
        }
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment:Fragment){
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

    private fun handleNavigationItemTap(item: MenuItem){
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.playlistFragmentItem -> replaceFragment(playlistFragment)
            R.id.singleStreamItem -> replaceFragment(streamFragment)
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    }
}
```

Comment: to make it easier for everyone else here, it could be worth adding in your existing code, so everyone else could copy paste that to try and help, just a suggestion

Comment: @a_local_nobody I added the code.